# How to list all tags pointing to a specific commit in git

Tags: git, tags

I have seen the commands `git describe` and `git-name-rev` but I have not managed to get them to list more than one tag.

Example: I have the sha1 48eb354 and I know the tags A and B point to it. So I want a git command `git {something} 48eb354` that produce output similar to "A, B". I am not interested in knowing references relative other tags or branches just exact matches for tags.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`git show-ref --tags -d | grep ^48eb354 | sed -e 's,.* refs/tags/,,' -e 's/\^{}//'`

should work for both lightweight and annotated tags.

Comment: This works well for git < 1.7.10. Can you explain what that second part of the sed expression does? `-e 's/\^{}//'`

Comment: Ah, nevermind, figured it out. It's for the `-d` option on `git show-ref`. From the docs, "-d, --dereference Dereference tags into object IDs as well. They will be shown with "^{}" appended."

Comment: Slight enhancement/generalization for using arbitrary `${ref}`, including annotated tags: `hash=$(git rev-parse "${ref}^0"); git show-ref --tags -d | sed -n -e 's,^'"${hash}"' refs/tags/\(.*\)^{}$',\1,p'`

Answer (score 248):

`git tag --points-at HEAD`

Shows all tags at HEAD, you can also substitute HEAD with any sha1 id.

Comment: Available from version 1.7.10: https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt

Answer (score 62):

You can use:

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

that shows all tags at certain commit.
It can be used instead of:

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

that is available only from 1.7.10.

Comment: NB: 'git tag --contains' doesn't show only the tags that point to the commit, but also includes any later tags that it's reachable from.

Comment: At least in version 2.6.4, this only returns a single tag that points to the specified commit.  It doesn't not return them all.  The answer above by @max seems to work properly for multiple tags.

Comment: `--contains` also appears much slower than `--points-at` (7-8s execution time vs < 1s)

Answer (score 6):

(Edit: This answer was written long before `git tag` had the `--points-at` switch – which is what you would use nowadays.)

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname:short)' refs/tags/ |
  grep ^$commit_id |
    cut -d' ' -f2
```

Pity it can’t be done more easily. Another flag on [`git tag`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html) to include commit IDs could express that `git for-each-ref` invocation naturally.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I seem not to be able to see the tags using this command either. Using the simpler "git for-each-ref | grep 48eb354" gives 0 matches. gitk on the other hand nicely lists the 2 tags in front of this commit.

Comment: This solution alone also works perfectly when the .git/objects folder is deleted! The solution i was looking for, to reduce the size of my docker build context. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For current commit you can use

```
git tag --points-at $(git log -n1 --pretty='%H')
```

Comment: Just use `HEAD` instead of `$(git log -n1 --pretty='%H')`

Answer (score 1):

The following command does the job, but directly parse the content of the .git directory and thus may break if the git repository format change.

```
grep -l -r -e '^48eb354' .git/refs/tags|sed -e 's,.*/,,'
```

Comment: Does not list them either, the only place I see the sha1 if grepping the entire .git folder is in gitk.cache and logs/refs/remotes/origin/master. How come gitk can list them ? I also notice that the tags I am looking at are annotated tags, this might be why the two current answers are not working for me.