# How to list all tags that contain a commit?

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

This question is similar to [How to list all tags pointing to a specific commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545370/how-to-list-all-tags-pointing-to-a-specific-commit-in-git), but with one difference: I wish to search for all tags that contain a specific commit within the tree of each tag, not specifically the files marked in the tag itself (in this case, only the Makefile change has been tagged).

Comment: You can't tag a particular file - tags only point to commits.  You might want to edit your question with more details of the problem that you're really trying to solve.

Comment: See also: [How to list branches that contain a given commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/git-how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit).

Comment: Note: on Windows, make sure to use git 2.0.x (2014) if you want `git tag --contains` to *not* crash. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24974192/6309)

Comment: There is also `git branch --contains <commit>` which does the same for branches. Needed both at the same time.

Answer (score 498, accepted):

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

Comment: I've tried this. But if the tag only contains one file, I believe it only searches through that file. It won't search the tree.

Also, the repository I tried it on is so large git bailed and got SIGKILL'ed.

Comment: Tags don't contain files. They're just markers for a commit. Given that, I don't think your objection makes sense.

Comment: It must not be showing me the commit because of lack of memory in that case. Do you know how I can get over this?

Comment: Is there any way to do this against remote tags? Similar to with branches: `git branch -r --contains <commit>`

Comment: note that this command can not be always trusted. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304574/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-an-equivalent-commit/26090892#26090892

Comment: @gatispaeglis That link is about a different question. If you want to find tags containing a commit, this is how you do it. Finding commits with an identical diff is a different thing, and not very common to need. The answer you link to would be terrible advice to give to someone who just wants to find tags containing an actual commit.

Answer (score 30):

Note that you need git 2.0.x (Q3 2014) in order to list all tags for a certain commit **if you have a large repo**

See [commit cbc60b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbc60b67201e083a4970c8731c5382a575357e36) by [Jean-Jacques Lafay (`lanfeust69`)](https://github.com/lanfeust69):

#### `git tag --contains`: avoid stack overflow

> In large repos, the recursion implementation of [`contains(commit, commit_list)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/996b0fdbb4ff63bfd880b3901f054139c95611cf/builtin/tag.c#L139-L140) may result in a stack overflow. Replace the recursion with a loop to fix it.
>
> This problem is more apparent on Windows than on Linux, where the stack is more limited by default.

See also [this thread on the msysGit list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/msysgit/FqT6boJrb2g/discussion).

Comment: No pun intended?  ;-)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Well... not an *intentional* one, at least.