# Git show tags a commit is on

Tags: git

How can I show the tags a commit is on in git?

For branches, this can easily be done by `git branch --contains <commit>`.

However, tags may not belong to any branches at all, in the case that it is archived by referencing it with a tag but deleting the branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all tags that contain a commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit)

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer after googling a bit more, the following prints the tags and branches containing a particular commit:

```
git describe --all --contains <commit>
```