# How to find out which release(s) contain a given GIT commit?

Tags: git, github

Someone fixed a bug in HHVM in this commit:

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/796f986aba300b3f00b9ece0bf654c452ee217be

I want to know if this commit is already part of the official [releases](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/releases).

Is there a way to list the releases/tags that contain this commit, either on GitHub, or in a local clone of the GIT repository on my machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list branches that contain a given commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419623/how-to-list-branches-that-contain-a-given-commit)

Comment: I assume that the versions have been tagged. If so, then see: [How to tell which commit a tag points to in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862423/how-to-tell-which-commit-a-tag-points-to-in-git)

Comment: Here's a better one [How to list all tags that contain a commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit).

Comment: Indeed that's a dup, sorry guys. At least on this project, releases and tags are identical. Can someone write an answer and point to the solution?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As pointed out by fellow members in the comments, this is already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7923091/759866), and is as easy as:

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

Answer (score 70):

GitHub now shows you the tags containing a commit automatically when you open a commit (click on the `...` to show all tags):

[image]

Comment: what does it mean if there is no branch or tag info like here https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/3c259c8a2f092c8e323406e4cf85c5c9a20baa55 ?

Comment: OlegYch: They are [dangling commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefdanglingobjectadanglingobject) which [will be removed after a while with `gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual/2.1.4#checking-for-corruption).