# Find out which release contain a given GIT commit via git describe and git tag

Tags: git

I have followed the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886537/how-to-find-out-which-releases-contain-a-given-git-commit) to try to find out which release contains a given git commit.

```
git tag --contains 8f873c1ff4ca034626093d03b254e7cb8bb782dd
```

It gives me a list from *v3.17 to v3.19-rc7*.

I also found there is another command can do this

```
git describe --tag 8f873c1ff4ca034626093d03b254e7cb8bb782dd
```

But it give me a different result, *v3.16-rc5-211-g8f873c1*. Notice that the previous result, *v3.17 to v3.19-rc7*, doesn't contain any v3.16.x version.

Acturally, I have used `git checkout <tags>` to manually search,  then I found that the given commit was first introduced at v3.16.2.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe give a diagram of the merges, because we do not have your repository.

Comment: `git describe` searches backwards unless you specify --contains

Comment: Given the tag names I would guess it's the Linux kernel source (`git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`).

Comment: Yes, it is linux kernel source repository.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two different questions.

`git describe --tag 8f873c1ff4ca034626093d03b254e7cb8bb782dd` gives you the description of a *specific* commit.  It starts with the given commit, then works *backwards* until it finds a tag and gives you an answer of the form `<tag>-<count>-g<commit_id>`, which tells that commit `<commit_id>` is `<count>` commits after `<tag>`.

`git tag --contains 8f873c1ff4ca034626093d03b254e7cb8bb782dd` is asking for *a list* of *tags* that *contain* the given commit...which means that any tag provided in the output of this command is going to be *newer* than the specified commit.  That is, this command is searching in the opposite direction of the previous command.

So since you're asking two very different questions, you're getting two different answers.