# Map a Git commit to a release/tag

Tags: git, github

In GitHub, is there a way to view a particular commit and then map this to the associated tag/release that it was included in?

I realize I can do this with git log, but that requires checking out the repo - I'm looking for a solution through the web interface, if it exists.

Comment: What do you mean by “map this”?

Comment: In a local repo [git name-rev](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-name-rev) is more suitable than `git log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through the GitHub UI - click on any commit in a repo's history, and if it was included in a tag or release, you'll see the release/tag number in the header section along the top:

[image: Sample commit with release tag highlighted]

If no release/tag number appears, then the commit hasn't been included in a tag or release yet.

[Here's the commit in the image above.](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html/commit/ad0ded932a1e3461eef7f36063aad52e594c20bd)

[Here's a similar answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47286371/866021)

Comment: Ahh!!!! I was on the history page for a particular file... Once you click the actual commit and view all of the other artifacts included in that commit, the information shows at the top (i.e. your screenshot). Thank you!!