# GitHub : Tags that include a specific commit

Tags: git, github, github-api

On Github, when you access the page corresponding to a commit - [like this](https://github.com/apache/cloudstack/commit/a5a5f612ea4fbdb37b6dc5c708fd042b00902f84) - you can see the following:

[image: Commit page]

I imagine that next to the branch (`master`) the page is showing the repository tags that include that specific commit (in this case: `4.8.0, 4.7.1, 4.7.0, 4.6.2, 4.6.1` and `4.6.0`).

Is there a way to access that information through GitHub REST API, or through GIT command line tools?

Comment: After cloning the repository, `git tag --contains a5a5f612e` like in  answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7923114/5781248

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to access that information through GitHub REST API, or through GIT command line tools?

You can get a list of all your tags in various ways.

---

## ***`GitHub API`***

> Get a Tag
>     `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/tags/:sha`

The response:

```
{
  "tag": "v0.0.1",
  "sha": "940bd336248efae0f9ee5bc7b2d5c985887b16ac",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags/940bd336248efae0f9ee5bc7b2d5c985887b16ac",
  "message": "initial version\n",
  "tagger": {
    "name": "Scott Chacon",
    "email": "schacon@gmail.com",
    "date": "2014-11-07T22:01:45Z"
  },
  "object": {
    "type": "commit",
    "sha": "c3d0be41ecbe669545ee3e94d31ed9a4bc91ee3c",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits/c3d0be41ecbe669545ee3e94d31ed9a4bc91ee3c"
  }
}
```

---

## ***`git log`***

```
git log --decorate --graph --oneline
```

[image]

---

## ***`git tag`***

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

> ***`--contains [<commit>]`***
>   Only list tags which contain the specified commit (HEAD if not specified).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the REST API URL is correct? I tried with the URL included in your example and got a 404: https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags/940bd336248efae0f9ee5bc7b2d5c985887b16ac

Comment: Looks like you have empty tags: https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about the REST API, but you can do this from Git's CLI

```
git tag --contains <commit>
```

This will output all tags reachable from this commit. `<commit>` can be a commit or object... ie a branch name, tag name, or sha.