# How can you tell if a PR on Github that's merged has made it into a release?

Tags: github

I'm looking at [a PR on Github](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/4787). It's been merged into Master. How do I know if this PR actually made it into a release?

Perhaps it can be [done using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit) which would require cloning the repo to your local machine but that's a lot of work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all tags that contain a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit)

Comment: Using the commit ID of a commit in the PR, and the tag ID of the release you are interested in.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to clone the repo locally just to check this. Wonder if there's another way...

Answer (score 21):

I found the answer on how to get the tag of a merged pull request (takes a few clicks) and see which release a PR made into:

1. Go to PR ([this one for example](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/4787))
2. Copy the PR number, enter it in the search and choose `In this repository` option: [image]
3. Click on a commit relating to that PR:
   [image]
4. Now you'll see that tag number at the bottom of the commit message:
   [image]

Comment: Does this work if the PR was deleted? I cannot see any commits anymore when I search for 4787 in the expo/expo repo example you gave @gezim. Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ky6auG9

Comment: Good question! I just tried the above process using this PR from django: https://github.com/django/django/pull/15621 .. it still works but not sure why the exact example above no longer does 

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Could it be something to do with a "squash and merge" on the PR branch?  (btw, I meant "PR branch was deleted" and not "PR was deleted" in my first comment, can't seem to edit it now :/)

Comment: The expo example stopped working because the github releases/tags were all deleted: https://github.com/expo/expo/tags -- compare that to [wayback machine from 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20210603212214/https://github.com/expo/expo/tags)

Comment: Simplifying the steps, scroll down the PR page until you find "merged commit $abc123"; clicking $abc123 gets you to step 4.

Comment: From what I've been able to make out, it's actually the earliest shown tag in the list (non-bold) that identifies the first to include the commit.