# How do I ask git for all the tags on a specific commit?

Tags: git

How do I ask git for all the tags on a specific commit?

I feel like this should be easy but I am not finding it in the man pages. Do I need to do multiple commands for this?

Comment: I think this should be what you're looking for: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546826/6142587)

Comment: git tag --points-at <commit>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all tags pointing to a specific commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545370/how-to-list-all-tags-pointing-to-a-specific-commit-in-git)