# How to get the commit TAGS, via git and not from predefined vars, when gitlab CI/CD triggers

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

### Update:

I solved that and i added my solution, on the bottom, for reference.

### Update:

After searching and digging i found a git script that gives the version tag:
`git log --decorate -n 1 --oneline | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f`.
So that command, **local on my the terminal**, gives just the version tag : `v1.0.7`

But when this **git** is executed inside the `gitlab-ci.yml` file, it returns always **nothing/empty**.

**gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
      ...
      export USER_TAG=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
      export STAGE_TAG=$(git log --decorate -n 1 --oneline $USER_TAG | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f1 | xargs)
      echo "*ver tag: $STAGE_TAG"
```

**It is like the git command is ignored, i dont know why this is happening, i need to search again**.

---

I m creating my `gitlab-ci.yml` file so that the Ci/CD pipeline starts when i push tags.

I need to make the pipeline start on **specific** combination of **2 TAGS**, **a version e.g. v1.0.0 and DEV_TEST** and not on just one TAG.

My commit that triggers the pipeline is like so (**<DEV_TEST><v1.0.7>**):
[image]

Into my `gitlab-ci.yml` i have a script that takes the `$CI_COMMIT_TAG`, but it just takes the `DEV_TEST` tag and ignores the `version tag`:

```
build:dev:
  stage: build:dev
  only:
    refs:
      - /^DEV_TEST/
  script: |
    set -e
    echo
    echo
    echo "################################################################################"
    echo "# Building Docker Base Image"
    echo "################################################################################"
    echo
    echo

    # ---- build image from branch ---- #
    if [ "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" != "" ]; 
    # ---- Build image from tag ---- # 
      then echo "building from tag branch $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
      docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE -f Dockerfile .
      docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
      docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG

      export TAG_VERSION=$(echo $CI_COMMIT_TAG | cut -d '-' -f1)

    fi
```

What i do is:

- push a version tag first, e.g. v1.0.0
- push the tag `DEV_TEST`, and based on the rule, the pipeline starts
- **but this line: then echo "building from tag branch $CI_COMMIT_TAG"
  gives the `DEV_TEST` tag only. So i m wondering is there a way to get both tags ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all tags pointing to a specific commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545370/how-to-list-all-tags-pointing-to-a-specific-commit-in-git)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Actually i get the one tag from predefined variable, as i show on my script`: `CI_COMMIT_TAG` and i miss the version tag. I manage to get the version tag if i run the above command on my terminal like so: `git log --decorate -n 1 --oneline | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f1` , so far so good.  Now the issue is that this git command returns nothing, inside the `gitlab-ci.yml`.   To answer your question, those answers are not as i need because i need to get just the version tag and not all the tags of the commit.

Comment: ok i found the issue for ignoring git. 
we need to install git,
in the `gitlab-ci.yml`
- apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py-pip git
- pip install awscli botocore==1.26.1
All good now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the version tag from the commit, like so:

in `gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
export USER_TAG=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
export VERSION_TAG=$(git log --decorate -n 1 --oneline $USER_TAG | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f1 | xargs)
```

So, in a commit with a version **tag** e.g. `v1.0.10` and another **tag** e.g. `DEV_TEST`, it will return the `v1.0.10` tag.

One challenge that exists here, is that **the git should be installed** into `yml` file, in order to run the commands.

So if it is not, and the commands cannot executed, we install git like so:

A good place to put it is on the `before script`.

```
before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - apk add --no-cache curl jq python3 py-pip git
  - pip install awscli botocore==1.26.1
```

Now all are in place, and the `git log ...` will be executed and return correct values.

I leave it here for reference, in case someone else wants to get the same values. (tag version from commit).